# Remember Me Login Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

When the user goes to my login, I am trying to get *remember me* to work. I have been trying to understand the best method of setting a **Remember Me** with a database and my login controller.

What is the best practice of implementing the *remember me* on my login view form with my controller?

Examples would be useful as well.

Login Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Login extends MX_Controller {

        private $error = array();

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function index() {

            $this->load->model('admin/user/user');

            $this->document->setTitle('Administration');

            if (($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
                redirect('admin/common/dashboard');
            }

            if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
                $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
            } else {
                $data['error_warning'] = '';
            }

            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');
            $remember = $this->input->post('remember');

            if (isset($username)) {
                $data['username'] = $username;
            } else {
                $data['username'] = '';
            }

            if (isset($password)) {
                $data['password'] = $password;
            } else {
                $data['password'] = '';
            }

            if (isset($remember)) {
                $data['remember'] = $remember;
            } else {
                $data['remember'] = '';
            }

            $data['header'] = Modules::run('admin/common/header/index');
            $data['footer'] = Modules::run('admin/common/footer/index');

            return $this->load->view('template/common/login', $data);
        }

        public function validate() {
            $username = $this->input->post('username');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

            if (!isset($username) || !isset($password) || !$this->user->login($username, $password)) {
                $this->error['warning'] = 'The login information is incorrect!';
            }
            return !$this->error;
        }
    }
```

Login View

```
<?php echo form_open('admin'); ?>

<br>
<div class="form-group input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-tag"></i></span>
    <input name="username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Your Username">
</div>

<div class="form-group input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
    <input name="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Your Password">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember">Remember me</label>
    <span class="pull-right"><a href="#">Forget password ? </a></span>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login Now</button>
<hr>
Not register?
<a href="">click here </a>

<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend you don't provide such a feature, unless you are willing to re-structure your code base to implement the feature(safely).

Cookies are **not** a secure method for persistent log ins.

You would need to pass the cookie an identifier such as username/email, the latter **should not** be used for privacy reason's.  You would also need to supply a hash/token **not** a password, again for privacy reasons.

You would need to re-generate a **new** token **after** each successful "remember me" login and re-generate a new cookie.

Now the tricky part.
If you user logs in in through the remember me method, you would want to restrict his/her access, ie: **don't** give them access to **sensitive data**, **change passwords**, **update bank account details**,**make purchases**

**ONLY** when they sign in providing you with a valid username/password combination should they then have full access again.

### Some steps to follow

1. If a use clicks remember me, generate a token and store it in DB.
2. set a cookie with the username, maybe encrypt->encode it along with token.
3. take usual login steps.
4. next time the user hits login url, check for cookie
5. encrypt->decode username/token from cookie and verify it against what's in DB.
6. bypass login and set session data for user
7. restrict access to profile stuff
8. re-generate new token, store it and re-generate new cookie details

I know this is not the answer you are looking for, but it might give you some in-sight.

Comment: You have any examples on setting cookie with encrypt and db etc

Comment: I don't have any examples, I would have to write one out for you which would be lengthy.

Comment: The advantage of this method will be if attacker however gots the cookie he can access the account for one time only. am i right?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a checkbox then you can pass *remember me* data as on/off. I think this might help you:

```
$this->load->library('cookie');

if ($postarr['eRemember'] == 'on') {
    $cookiedata = array(
        'nspl_username' => $postarr['vUsername'],
        'nspl_password' => $postarr['vPassword']
    );
    $this->cookie->write('userarray', $cookiedata);
} else {
    $cookiedata = array(
        'nspl_username' => '',
        'nspl_password' => ''
    );
    $this->cookie->write('userarray', $cookiedata);
}
```

Comment: What would be best way to make it work in my controller and then what would I need for other controllers

Comment: Just place this code within your `loginaction` of your controller and can be used within your other controller's

Answer (score -2):

It's very easy.

Just load cookie helper and create cookies while login and set the cookie value in the input fields if the cookie is there. You should have to set this while the checkbox is checked.